# Can Microsoft Graph filter out Junk Email?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=isRead eq false` in Microsoft Graph Explorer to return a list of my unread emails. My goal is to have a simple HUD on my website that shows a notification to any logged-in user how many unread messages they have waiting for them in Outlook.

The problem is this returns all unread emails in my Junk Email folder in addition to my legitimate unread emails. I would like to filter out Junk Email, but graph doesn't give me a way to systemically accomplish this for all users.

All emails have a `parentFolderID`, and Graph says the email in my Junk email folder has `"parentFolderId": "AQMkAGFjOGFkNWM2LTcxMjQtND..."`. This means I could filter out my own Junk Email, but that doesn't help the rest of my users since they would each have a unique `parentFolderID` for their Junk Email.

I could create a rule for myself that marks Junk Email as read, but I can't expect my users to do something like that.

Any thoughts on how I can filter out Junk Email for all users?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think a single query to the Graph API will solve this problem, but you can do multiple calls with a little bit of logic to solve this.

1. List all mailFolders

   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders`
2. Find the 'Junk Email' folder

```js
var json = `
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')/mailFolders",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAAuAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURAQAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEkAAA=",
            "displayName": "Junk Email",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAAuAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURAQAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEIAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 0,
            "unreadItemCount": 0,
            "totalItemCount": 0
        }
    ]
}`

var obj = JSON.parse(json)

for(var folder in obj.value)
{
  if (obj.value[folder].displayName == 'Junk Email')
  {
    document.write(obj.value[folder].id)
    break
  }
}
```

3. Filter out messages from that folder as you described, uniquely per user.

Comment: This set me on the correct path. The "unreadItemCount" for the Inbox folder is what I actually needed to get.

Answer (score 1):

To get a count of unread mail from ONLY my inbox, I ended up using:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$filter=displayName eq 'Inbox'`

which returns:

`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('ed313cf6-f369-45c6-94b2-48bbb3589788')/mailFolders",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkAGFjOGFkNWM2LTcxMjQtNDQ4My1iNjBlLTVhZmNiNTA3ZTcwNQAuAAAAAAAcAJPfHQ_aQputXsbIt-bZAQC5oqQhrW6CRI4cZpo9l5YaAA7BDDZpAAA=",
            "displayName": "Inbox",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGFjOGFkNWM2LTcxMjQtNDQ4My1iNjBlLTVhZmNiNTA3ZTcwNQAuAAAAAAAcAJPfHQ_aQputXsbIt-bZAQC5oqQhrW6CRI4cZpo9l5YaAA7BDDZmAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 14,`
            **`"unreadItemCount": 1,`**
            `"totalItemCount": 25
        }
    ]
}`

The data I'm after is in `"unreadItemCount"`. Thanks for Shawn Tabrizi for setting me on the correct path with `/me/mailFolders`.

Please note that you currently cannot filter `/me/messages` by parentFolderId, so you would need to run custom filtering code like Shawn Tabrizi had suggested if you want to get any mail content from `/me/messages`.

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The property 'ParentFolderId' does not support filtering.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "526bafdd-d8ac-47f2-be1f-656b3b93da35",
            "date": "2017-10-11T15:45:33"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can run two separate queries to get all new emails in the inbox folder and their content data.

1. First run:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$filter=displayName eq 'Inbox'`

to get details on the Inbox folder only.

`$filter=displayName eq 'Inbox'` filters folders with `displayName` equal to (`eq`) 'Inbox'

This returns:

```
`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('9285d2c9-f210-45e1-b78e-d74ba3d5e186')/mailFolders",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADRlM2I0YmM5LWI2MTUtNDgzZC04N2M0LWJmMWU1MTFjMDBiYwAuAAAAAAB1tij3RiDhRab9QpP_GQhpAQCTj9cyjezTSYJYfMfg3p5fAAAAAAEMAAA=",
            "displayName": "Inbox",
            "parentFolderId": "AAMkADRlM2I0YmM5LWI2MTUtNDgzZC04N2M0LWJmMWU1MTFjMDBiYwAuAAAAAAB1tij3RiDhRab9QpP_GQhpAQCTj9cyjezTSYJYfMfg3p5fAAAAAAEIAAA=",
            "childFolderCount": 0,
            "unreadItemCount": 1,
            "totalItemCount": 0
        }
    ]
}`
```

2. To get the content data you need the `id` value to form part of the second query.

Add `&$count=true` to the end to get the count of unread emails in Inbox:

Second query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{ Inbox id goes here }/messages?$filter=isRead eq false&$count=true`

This filters the unread (`isRead eq false`) from the Inbox folder and returns something like:

```
`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('9285d2c9-f210-45e1-b78e-d74ba3d5e186')/mailFolders('AAMkADRlM2I0YmM5LWI2MTUtNDgzZC04N2M0LWJmMWU1MTFjMDBiYwAuAAAAAAB1tij3RiDhRab9QpP_GQhpAQCTj9cyjezTSYJYfMfg3p5fAAAAAAEMAAA%3D')/messages",
"@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACTj9cyjezTSYJYfMfg3p5fAACWjeF5\"",
            "receivedDateTime": "2018-01-29T11:32:40Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2018-01-29T11:32:37Z",
            "subject": "New Mail",
            "bodyPreview": "New email body for email preview",
            "isRead": false,
            "isDraft": false,
            -- More properties are returned. Shortened response for brevity --
```

`

Email content data are acceessed via `value`.

Count of unread emails in Inbox folder is accessed via `odata.count`.

See [Microsof Graph - List messages in a specified folder in the mailbox](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/mailfolder_list_messages)